# Retrofit Post Request with URL encoded body and user authentication

Tags: retrofit, okhttp

I am trying to create a request using retrofit with a key-value (`&` separated) payload and simple user authentication, as it can be done in the following `curl` command:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=<refresh_token>" -u"<client_id>:<client_secret>" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

How can I create a request in retrofit that supplies the above data? I need both the interface method and the creation of `RequestBody` if it used.

**UPDATE:**

I used the following code

*interface method definition:*

```
@POST("/o/token/")
Observable<ServerToken> refreshAccessToken(@Header("Authorization") String auth, @Body RequestBody tokens);
```

*calling the implementation:*

```
    RequestBody body = new FormEncodingBuilder()
            .add("grant_type", "refresh_token")
            .add("refresh_token", serverToken.refresh_token)
            .build();

    String auth = Credentials.basic("<client_id>", "<client_secret>");
    mTokenApi.refreshAccessToken(auth, body)
```

But I am getting a `Content-Type: application/json` in the request and an empty request body.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: @Jonathan updated question. thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do it is:

*interface method definition:*

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/o/token/")
Observable<ServerToken> refreshAccessToken(@Header("Authorization") String auth,
                                           @Field("grant_type") String grantType,
                                           @Field("refresh_token") String refreshToken);
```

*calling the implementation:*

```
    String auth = Credentials.basic(clientID, clientSecret);
    mTokenApi.refreshAccessToken(auth, "refresh_token", serverToken.refresh_token)
```